# How to make get request using axios by the following code

Tags: reactjs, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I faced, Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" issue while trying to make get request using woocommerce rest api v3. I want to make get request by using axios modifying the header. So How to do this using this code below from axios?

```
const woocommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: process.env.REACT_APP_WP_URL,
  consumerKey: process.env.REACT_APP_WP_KEY,
  consumerSecret: process.env.REACT_APP_WP_SECRET,
  version: 'wc/v3',
  axiosConfig: {
    headers: {},
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` to the headers like so:

```
const api = new WooCommerceRestApi({
    url: url,
    consumerKey: consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: consumerSecret,
    version: "wc/v3",
    axiosConfig:{
      headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        }
    }
  });
```